# Prediction algorithm in ctree() function in R party package

Tags: prediction

I have a model that predicts categorical response using the conditional trees, ctree() function in R package "party". I am able to get predicted responses on the new data set after training the model on the training set.

My question is about communicating the prediction algorithm. How can I obtain the prediction algorithm from ctree() in an way so that someone else can use it to predict responses on a new data set. For example, in the case of the linear regression, I would report the coefficients for the predictors. I am not sure how to do it for conditional trees.

My model has 5 ordinal responses, and about 20 ordinal predictors.

Thanks in advance,
Shamil.